# Python randomly changing data Types

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, types, ipython

I think I have a bug in my python installation. The following code:

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    for key in F1Test.keys():

    mTest = np.append(mTest, float(F1Test[key]))
    i = i+1
```

will run for a random number of times before it crashes giving the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: error
```

F1Test has the following values:

```
In [123]: F1Test
 Out[123]: 
 {'AltoFlute': 0.75,
 'AltoSax': 1.0,
 'Bass': 0.9111111111111111,
 'BassClarinet': 0.8,
 'BassFlute': 0.8695652173913043,
 'BassTrombone': 'error',
 'Bassoon': 0.7692307692307692,
 'BbClarinet': 0.9230769230769231,
 'Cello': 0.8695652173913043,
 'EbClarinet': 0.9411764705882353,
 'Flute': 0.8695652173913044,
 'Guitar': 1.0,
 'Horn': 1.0,
 'Oboe': 0.8750000000000001,
 'Piano': 0.993103448275862,
 'SopSax': 0.9230769230769231,
 'TenorTrombone': 0.923076923076923,
 'Trumpet': 1.0,
 'Tuba': 0.888888888888889,
 'Viola': 0.8735632183908046,
 'Violin': 0.8974358974358975}
```

I found it in a larger code and got it reduced to this form. Apparently, once every 50th time it will read the values from the dictionary as strings instead of floats. I am using ipython 1.2.1, python 2.7.6 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I am not interested in a workaround (I know I can test for type and be done with it), I just find this interesting and I am looking to understand this problem.

Comment: It looks like it is trying to convert BassTrombone's 'error' to a float and failing.

Comment: is the value of the `F1Test[key]` that is erroring equal to `error`?

Comment: You are both right. In the larger code F1Test gets reinitialized for each loop and once in a while it must get an error. My eye didn't caught the string. Time to take a walk I guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`F1Test[key]` gets each value from your dict, then you cast to float with  `float(F1Test[key])`, you have a string in your dictionary `"error"` which you try casting to a float so obviously it will error. There is no way you will ever get the code to run without error unless using a `try/except`  or some other method to catch input that cannot be cast to a float.

On another note all the values bar `"error"` are already floats so casting is redundant, you also don't need to call `.keys` to iterate over the dict keys, `for key in dict` is sufficient, also if you just want the values use `dict.values()`.

Comment: I know, I casted the values in order to get an exception. In the larger code the exception came from a mean method called on the array. Thank you for reading my question and pointing this out. I got blocked.

Comment: No worries,  might be time for a break ;)